# How to fix Logitech mouse (M510) that switches to device status "inactive" all the time?

Tags: mouse

I'm using a Logitech M510 mouse on a MacBookPro (MacOS 10.14.2), connected via the Logitech Unifying Receiver. It was working completely fine for a long time.

Recently, it started to switch to Device Status = *inactive* frequently (as shown in the Logitech Unifying Software dialog).

Basically, it switches on and off all the time, and is unusable. As a side effect, it uses up batteries within 3 days.

I have already replaced the batteries.

Any hints, what I might try otherwise?

*edit:* I have another Logitech Mouse that shows the same symptoms (on the same laptop and Logitech Unifying receiver).

Comment: Define "a long time." What it sounds like is the mouse is dying and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Actually, the problem is with two Logitech mice, so I doubt it's the mouse. Could be the Logitech Unifying Receiver, but I rather suspect a software problem. Any other suggestions what to check?